# Cannot get Swiftmailer to work on a PHP site

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am new to PHP and Swiftmailer.
What I am trying to do is set up a PHP site on a webserver and use SwiftMailer to send e-mails.

The code I got does work on my local XAMPP server, but will produce the error message:

"Fatal error: Class 'Swift_Attachment' not found in /[address to my php file]"

when executed from the on-line webserver.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    // Get this directory, to include other files from
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);

    // Get the contents of the pdf into a variable for later
    ob_start();
    require_once($dir.'/pdf_selbst_lir.php');
    $pdf_html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // Load the dompdf files
    require_once($dir.'/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); // Create new instance of dompdf
    $dompdf->load_html($pdf_html); // Load the html
    $dompdf->render(); // Parse the html, convert to PDF
    $pdf_content = $dompdf->output(); // Put contents of pdf into variable for later    

    // Get the content of the HTML email into a variable for later
    ob_start();
    require_once($dir.'/Templates/html.php');
    $html_message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();                                                                 

    // Swiftmailer
    require_once($dir.'/swiftmailer-5.0.1/lib/swift_required.php'); 

    // Create the attachment with your data
    $attachment = Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content, 'pdfname.pdf', 'application/pdf');     

// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mymailserver', 587, 'tls')
        ->setUsername('username')
        ->setPassword('password')
        ;
    // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    // Create the message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()             
                ->setFrom(array('senderaddress' => 'Sender Name'))      
                ->setSubject('subject')
                ->addBcc('somebccaddress')              
                ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html')               
                ->attach($attachment);  

                try {
                 $message->addTo('somerecipient'); 
                    }
                catch (Swift_RfcComplianceException $e)
                    {
                        // Address was invalid
                        echo "Email address not correct.";
                    }   

    // Send the message
      if ($mailer->send($message))
              $success = true;
        else
                $error = true;

?>
```

Note that when I comment out all the attachment-related stuff, the error message switches to

"Fatal error: Class 'Swift_SmtpTransport' not found in /[address to my php file]" and points to the "$transport" line.

So it appears the overall SwiftMailer is not working, and this is not attachment-related.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case closed.

It turned out that the code was working fine after all. All I needed to do was upgrade Swiftmailer (now running on 5.4.2-DEV). Sorry for the hassle and thanks scaisEdge for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I don'see  ->setTo( your_mail_dest) and ->send()

try with a simple send like this

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()             
            ->setFrom(array('senderaddress' => 'Sender Name')) 
            ->setTo( **** your_mail_dest ****)     
            ->setSubject('subject')
            ->addBcc('somebccaddress')              
            ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html')               
            ->attach($attachment)
            ->send();
```